# JavaScript Object Method use super keyword

Tags: javascript, super

When my object method is function declaration super keyword work normally.

```js
const user = {
  name: "Murad"
};
const murad = {
  getName() {
    super.name
  },
  __proto__: user
};
```

But when I want to change function declaration to function expression JS return Error

```js
const user = {
  name: "Murad"
};
const murad = {
  getName: function() {
    super.name
  },
  __proto__: user
};
```

> Uncaught SyntaxError: 'super' keyword unexpected here
>   Why this happpened?

Comment: So so sorry I change my question code. And you can see first version work normally but second is not

Comment: It's not a function declaration, it's a method definition.

Answer (score 0):

> The super.prop and super[expr] expressions are valid in any ***method***
>   ***definition*** in both classes and object literals. [`super MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super)

In the first example it is used in a method so a valid expression

```js
const user = {
  name: "Murad"
};
const murad = {
  getName() {
    return super.name
  },
  __proto__: user
};

console.log(murad.getName())
```

---

Second one is not a method syntax as per ECMAScript [`Method definition section`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-method-definitions)

```js
const user = {
  name: "Murad"
};
const murad = {
  getName: function() {
    super.name
  },
  __proto__: user
};
```

Comment: This is so weird actually you say first is method but second property is which have value. But you can see in MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions) there are same thing. First one only shorthand.

Comment: @MuradSofiyev wait let me update it in more sensible manner

Comment: @MuradSofiyev MDN doesn't say that they are the same thing. It says that one can be shortened to the other.